# Possible Wine Substitutions for Sherry When Making French Onion Soup

Tags: substitutions, soup, wine

I am making French onion soup, and it calls for sherry. What would be a good substitute for the sherry?

Comment: Are you trying to avoid wine or just sherry? Also is the recipe using beef or chicken stock?

Comment: Sherry can often be used as a substitute for wine in small quantities, but in larger quantities you may find it's too sweet  (for all but the driest sherries)

Comment: Just use vinegar.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you can.  (I usually use wine, in fact).  Note that sherries are a fortified wine, so you may want to add a small amount of brandy as well; say 1 Tbl to 1/4 cup per cup of wine.

If you are using a chicken stock, restrict yourself to a white wine; perhaps a rose if you have a particularly dark chicken stock.

For a beef stock, red or white will work well.  In addition, if the recipe calls for a sweet sherry, you can also use a port or a Madeira.

In all cases, add in parts and taste between until you're happy with the result.

Answer (score 4):

1. Avoid 'cooking' sherry as too salty, overpriced, and of dubious taste.
2. **I suggest brandy if no suitable sherry is available.**
3. Avoid overly sweet sherries (e.g. cream finish); I like/use an Amontillado.

Answer (score 1):

I sometimes use cider and a splash of brandy or rum as a substitute for sherry